# Cardview with multiple background colors

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-cardview

I am currently busy with a details view page. I was now wondering how I can make a cardview look like the one I designed. I can't seem to find on google how to do so. I want the card to be multi colored: 25% of the top should be white, and the remaining 75 procent to the bottom should be red. How can I do so? I was thinking about drawables, but I think that it will look ugly with different phones.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have this cardview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/view4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Body3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Descriptie"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/material_grey_200" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Body2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/material_grey_600" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: u got solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a linear layout, set the width to fill parent and set it's background color.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/black"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey_600" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using weight and weightSum like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Body3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Descriptie"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_50"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_grey_600" 
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```